# Regex Match Multiline Chat Messages

Tags: regex

I am attemping to use regex to parse chat logs (namely Skype messages). So the regex I am currently using matches Skype logs correctly....as long as they don't have new lines.

So I tried adding the `s` modifier to the end, but this now makes it match everything (because its now multiline). So I was wondering if there was a way to both allow multiline, but stop before the `[`  at the beginning of Skype messages.

My regex is here: https://regex101.com/r/nL0vO9/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pZ6zU8/2  for the purpose of showing both matches on regex101, also added `g` modifier, but in reality, php doesn't have a `g` modifier so use `preg_match_all` for your actual code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [tempered greedy Token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
\[(?:(?!\n\[).)*
```

Note you also need to include g modifier so you don't stop on first match

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL0vO9/2)

Like @sln pointed out, if you want to keep new lines use this instead:

```
\[(?:.(?<!\n\[))*
```

Comment: Or this could also be `\[(?:.(?<!\n\[))*` which would allow the newline to be matched.

Comment: It works great on regex101, but when attempting to use ```preg_split```, it says ```Warning: preg_split(): Unknown modifier 'g'```. When removing it, preg_split returns an array with empty values.

Comment: use preg_match_all instead of the global modifier like @Crayon pointed out

Comment: Ah yes, its almost working now. It doesn't keep new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Set the flags to `//mg` multi-line and global. Don't use the `s` Dot all flag.
*edit:* I guess you could use something simpler if you don't care about validating/parsing out the time/name/message parts. Either @CrayonViolent or @RodrigoLópez should work for that.

```
 # ^\[([^\r\n\]]*)\]([^:\r\n]*):((?:(?!^\[).*(?:\r?\n)*)*)

 ^                             # BOL
 \[ 
 ( [^\r\n\]]* )                # (1), Time
 \] 
 ( [^:\r\n]* )                 # (2), Person
 :  
 (                             # (3 start), Message
      (?:                           # Cluster group
           (?! ^ \[ )                    # Assert, not BOL and [
           .*                            # Get all to end of line
           (?: \r? \n )*                 # Optional, Get 1 to many line-breaks
      )*                            # End cluster, do 1 to many times
 )                             # (3 end)
```